# Perl - can't remove trailing characters at the end of string

Tags: perl

I have some trailing characters at the end of a string `peregrinevwap^_^_`

```
print "JH 4 - app: $application \n";

app: peregrinevwap^_^_
```

Do you know why they are there and how I can remove them. I tried the `chomp` command but this hasn't worked.

Comment: You are running under windows or linux OS?

Comment: This is running on Linux OS

Comment: An where you edited yor script?

Comment: Directly on the unix box in vi.

Comment: They are not trailing characters if they are in the middle of the string ("_" is before the last "^").

Comment: I dont understand how "^_^_" has been stamped on the end of peregrinevwap

Comment: @Jaron787 Do you have copied a string from an other program? use a hex editor to see what character this are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `tr//cd` operator to get rid of unwanted characters.
It's documented in "`perldoc perlop`"

```
$application =~ tr/a-zA-Z//cd;
```

Will remove everything except letters from the string and

```
$application =~ tr/^_//d;
```

Will remove all "^" and "_" characters.

If you only want to remove certain characters when they at the end of the string, use the s// search/replace operator with regular expressions and the `$` anchor to match the end of the string.

Here's an example:

```
s/[\^_]*$//;
```

Let's hope the underscores do not occur at the end of your strings, otherwise you can't automatically separate them from these unwanted characters.

Comment: The problem with this is I have strings with "_" in them: app: ninjak_xlon

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these characters are actually `^` and `_` characters?
`^_` could also indicate Ctrl-Underscore, ASCII character 0x1F (Unit Separator).  (Not a character I've ever seen used, but you never know.)

If this is in fact the case, you can remove them with something like:

```
$application =~ s/\x1F//g;
```